# Adding translucent shader makes invisible plane somehow visible

Tags: node-editor

[image]

**strong text**I when I'm adding translucent shader, the invisible part of the plane is showing which is I don;t want**strong text**

Comment: Don't use the *Add Shader*. Either plug the alpha directly into *Principled BSDF* or use a *Mix Shader*.

Comment: thank you so muuuch

Comment: I can post this as a proper answer if it solved your problem.